# Email footer using inline HTML without CSS (problem with resize/table parts/clickable images)

Tags: html, email, footer

I'm trying to make an email footer from a specific background design but using only inline HTML without using CSS styles. Found a solution that You can edit the .htm file used by Outlook in this case (located in C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures) and paste other code. Background image is made in CS6 Photoshop where email/phone information is changed there and exported. The design cannot be changed cause it has been accepted from above so I have to work with this what I got... Above image contains 4 icons to proper social media which have to be links. On the other hand, it has to be sizeable if You see a message for example on phone.

I tried:

- to chop every image and place them properly on one table with background-image from url using tr/td and using margin/padding=0 but while it looks ok on Outlook when I send it to for example Gmail it completely shatters...
- making one image with the above options as well and adding colspan/rowspan to merge cells for example 3x6 table where:
  ** first column is rowspan="3" corresponding to this vertical line in an image where basic informations are provided [part: 1]
  ** upper part as colspan="6" to make one big space with information values [part: 2]
  ** middle part is 5 times <a href="[link]" for clickable icons [part: 3-6]
  ** below part used once more colspan="6" to make big space with secondary information values [part: 7]

Image with marked parts.
[Image_parts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYVeO.png)

Footer should looks like this:
[Footer_One_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8yGm.jpg)

Code which I tried to use for above image:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table { 
        background: url("https://i.postimg.cc/xCr58mYc/przyk-adowa-stopka.jpg") no-repeat;
        width: 1200px;
        height: 400px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4" width="332"></td>
    <td colspan="6" height="250"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="10">
      <a href="https://google.com"></a>
    </td>
    <td width="63" height="50">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"></a>
    </td>
    <td width="63" height="50">
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
    </td>
    <td width="80" height="50">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/"></a>
    </td>
    <td width="63" height="50"></td>
    <td colspan="2" height="50"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Also I tried using this one which chopped images generated from photoshop as a .htm file (I deleted links) but when placed in outlook looks fine - while I send it to any other mail webservice it collapses.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>stopka 1</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (stopka 1.psd) -->
<table id="Tabela_01" width="1200" height="400" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img src="" width="339" height="400" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="4">
            <img src="" width="861" height="250" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="">
                <img src="" width="86" height="78" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
        <td>
            <a href="">
                <img src="" width="67" height="78" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
        <td>
            <a href="">
                <img src="" width="89" height="78" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
        <td>
            <a href="">
                <img src="" width="619" height="78" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <img src="" width="861" height="72" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

How I can manage to write this where I'm kinda pretty much failing. Thank You for any advice/information. Have a nice day.

Comment: What do you mean by, it collapses? Could you provide a screenshot of that as well?

Comment: After sending this to any other webmail server It looks like this:
https://i.postimg.cc/4xBn83TL/image.png